# Decimal to Fraction in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I wrote this simple script to convert a decimal to a fraction but it is not working. Nothing is outputted.

```
var decimal = 1.75;
var decimalArray = decimal.split("."); // 1.75
var leftDecimalPart = decimalArray[0]; // 1
var rightDecimalPart = decimalArray[1]; // 75

var numerator = leftDecimalPart + rightDecimalPart; // 175
var denominator = Math.pow(10, rightDecimalPart.length); // 100

document.write(numerator + " / " + denominator);
```

JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/exepir/1/edit

Comment: Why? I tried 1.75 and it worked.

Comment: You have wrong output. `numerator/denominator` will give the fraction, not vice versa.

Comment: @bfavaretto for 0.2 it returns `02 / 10` which is correct. Nothing suggests it would be a reduced fraction.

Comment: I failed to see the whole picture, VisioN is right. On your current code numerator and denominator are inverted.

Comment: Fixed document.write(numerator + " / " + denominator);

Comment: @user1822824 see [Is there a javascript function that reduces a fraction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652468/is-there-a-javascript-function-that-reduces-a-fraction) for how to reduce fractions if you want to implement that.

Comment: I don't want to reduce. I have a separate function for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't "split" numbers.

If you look at the console, you'll see

> Uncaught TypeError: Object 1.75 has no method 'split'

You should be using the JavaScript section on JSBin, it'll show you errors like this in a red box at the bottom.

Easiest fix? Make it a string by either writing it as a string literal:

```
var decimal = '1.75';
```

Or call `.toString()` before splitting:

```
var decimalArray = decimal.toString().split(".");
```

And numerator is on top:

```
document.write(numerator + " / " + denominator);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since working with strings is not the best way to solve your problem, I'd suggest you a fast alternative solution which works with numbers only:

```
var decimal = 1.75,
    numerator = decimal,
    denominator = 1;

while (numerator % 1) numerator *= 10;
denominator = numerator / decimal;

console.log(numerator + " / " + denominator);
// >> "175 / 100"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure it works in the general case, I would rely on a well tested library, like [Fraction.js](https://github.com/infusion/Fraction.js).

```
var f = new Fraction(1.75);

console.log(f.toFraction()); // Results "1 3/4"
console.log(f.s * f.n + " / " + f.d); // Results "7 / 4"
console.log(f.toString()); // Results "1.75"
```