# Convert decimals to fraction of nearest 1/16 using Fraction.js

Tags: javascript, math, fractions

I'm working on an old Angularjs app, and I need to be able to convert numbers in decimal format to fractions of the nearest 1/16. I've been searching for a few hours, and the one option I've found that seems to be the best is [Fraction.js](https://github.com/infusion/Fraction.js). However, when following examples such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30643617/391054), I get improper fractions. For example:

```
  var convertToFraction = function (decimal) {
    // Round to the neareest 1/16
    var f = new Fraction(decimal);
    var newVal = f.toFraction();

    return newVal;
  };
```

I get `157293/2000"` if I pass in a value of `78.6465`, `3/2` if I pass in a value of `1.500`. For the `78.6465`, I would want to get `78 5/8`.

Is there something else I need to do to get it to return the value in proper form, not improper fraction form? Also, do I need to do my own rounding of the decimal to the nearest 1/16 before passing the value to `Fraction`, like so?

```
  var convertToFraction = function (decimal) {
    // Round to the nearest 1/16
    var rounded = (Math.round(decimal * 16) / 16).toFixed(3);
    var f = new Fraction(rounded);
    var newVal = f.toFraction();
    return newVal;
  };
```

Even with that, I still get an improper format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the proper fractions, I just had to pass the `true` argument to `toFraction()`:

```
var newVal = f.toFraction(true);
```