# How to efficiently convert an integer into string polar coordinate?

Tags: javascript, performance, coding-efficiency

Given integers 0-24, I have to convert them to a polar theta in radians as a string. Ex: 0 = '0', 1 = 'pi/12', 2 = 'pi/6' etc. The `pi` should be an actual pi symbol. I think that my solution is inefficient. Here is what I do:

```
var fracStrings = ['0/1', '1/12', '1/6', '1/4', '1/3', '5/12', '1/2', '7/12', '2/3', '3/4', '5/6', '11/12', '1/1', '13/12', '7/6', '5/4', '4/3', '17/12', '3/2', '19/12', '5/3', '7/4', '11/6', '23/12', '2/1'];

function nToString(n){
     //converts angle to string representation
     var num = (fracStrings[n].split('/')[0] == 1) ? '' : fracStrings[n].split('/')[0];
     num = (fracStrings[n].split('/')[0] == 0) ? '0' : num + '\u03C0';
     var denom = (fracStrings[n].split('/')[1] == 1) ? '' : '/' + fracStrings[n].split('/')[1];
     return '' + num + denom;
 }
```

I find it inefficient to declare a fractions string. My problem is simplifying the fraction. I cannot have 12pi/12, I just need pi. Is there an efficient way to do this? This just hurts to look at.

FYI: `\u03C0` is the pi symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the pi symbol directly in the strings in the array.

```
const fracStrings = ['0', 'π/12', 'π/6', ...];
```

or

```
const fracStrings = ['0', '\u03C0/12', '\u03C0/6', ...];
```

Then the function is simple:

```
function nToString(n) {
    return fracStrings[n];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you think there's a way without initially defining a string? This still feels too hardcoded. Unfortunately, I could not find any libraries that can handle this fraction simplification.

Comment: Anything else is going to be complicated, because there's nothing built in to simplify fractions. If we were talking about an array of hundreds of items it might be worthwhile, but with only 24 elements the array is the best way.

Comment: Here’s a really short function to simplify fractions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652468/is-there-a-javascript-function-that-reduces-a-fraction